# How can I find the optimal parameters for a function?

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, search, optimization

I have a function in Python with the parameters x1,x2,x3,...xn and output of true or false.
The function scans a dataset and uses the values of each row to decide if the row should have a target value of true or false.

How can I find the optimal parameters (xn) for the function in a way that will take the least amount of time?

I know what the target values should be so I want to find parameters that will let the function predict the target at high accuracy.

FYI: there will be around 15 parameters each can have roughly 10 possible values.

For example:

```
def func_1(n, x, y, y_2):
    score_1 = score_2 = 0
    if n > 5:
        score_1 = score_1 + (x * y)
    if n < 5:
        score_2 = score_2 + (x * y_2)
    return (score_1, score_2)
```

Also, what if the number of parameters was limited to 5 with 10 possible values for each?

Comment: This problem is not solvable in general. If the function is linear in all the variables, the subject of Linear Programming has your solution, probably the simplex method. If it's nonlinear, it's much tougher, although it'll be easier if the function is continuous and has periods of being monotonic. In general though, without these conditions, it's not solvable. Basically we need much more information than you have provided to even have a shot at answering this one.

Comment: I agree with @cazort that a lot more information is needed, but depending on that info a solution may be do-able using design of experiments and response surface modeling. If the factors are discrete-valued with 10 categories, that means there are 10^15 possible combos and the outcomes may be chaotic - adjacent points could yield wildly different results.  If the factors can be viewed as continuous but you've only measured them at ten levels, and if the outcomes shift consistently in each dimension, then response surface methods might be able to get a good toehold on the problem.

Comment: The function is mostly "if" statements. For example, if var_1 > var_2 then return x3 where var_1 and 2 are from the dataset and x3 is one of the parameters.

Comment: @HubertRzeminski In cases like that you might actually have the best luck reading through the function and figuring out what it's doing at each step, and picking the parameters accordingly. I know stuff with tons of cases and/or nested if statements are often enough to make your brain explode, but sometimes if you can power through it mentally you'll see the answer plainly staring at you in the code. It might also help if you know what this function is intending to do or why it does what it does.

Comment: Can you provide a scaled down concrete example with code?  Right now it's all pretty hand-wavy.

Comment: I have included an example, the scores returned are later used to decide the target value e.g. if score_1 > score_2 then the target is True.

Comment: I'm compltely lost with your "optimal parameters" issue. I can work with a geometrical function where I want its minimum or find the sortest path or alike. Can you enlighten what's your function about?

Comment: The function returns two values which are used to assign True or False to a row in the dataset. The same way as a classification model in machine learning would do. And the "optimal parameters" are the best values for "xn" so that the accuracy of the function is at its heighest.

Comment: Your code example doesn't agree with the problem description.  In comments you said "the scores returned are later used to decide the target value e.g. if score_1 > score_2 then the target is True", so that's the sort of code you should be showing in the question -- people shouldn't need to read the comments to understand the question. I also agree with others that you haven't defined what you mean by "optimal".

Comment: Are you trying to optimize decision boundaries for a given decision tree? Construct an optimal decision tree? I'm very confused.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I completely understand your intention. In particular, I am a little confused by the fact that you first talk about a boolean target function, but then gives an example of a function which returns a numeric value. Nevertheless, your question made me think.

The problem, as I understand it, is the following: we're given a boolean function `g(x)`, and we know that `g(x) = f(params ; x)` for some appropriate parameters. We have to find parameters which give a good approximation to `g`. In other words, we have a model `f(params ; x)`, and we have to train it to approximate `g(x)`.

The natural way to do so is to use some optimization algorithm. The first one that comes to mind is **Gradient Descent**. But this algorithm is of no use in this case, because it requires a differentiable target function, and our function is not guaranteed to be differentiable. In fact, if I understand correctly, it is a discrete function (the parameters can take a finite number of possible values). So we have to think of something else.

Another popular optimization method is the so called **Genetic Algorithm**, which does not depend on gradients, and is therefore applicable for discrete problems.

A quick reminder of how a genetic algorithm in its simplest form works (a very good introduction can be found in https://www.whitman.edu/Documents/Academics/Mathematics/2014/carrjk.pdf):

1. We represent each possible solution ("chromosome") as a sequence of numbers ("genes"): `x1, x2, ..., xn`.
2. We randomly choose a certain number of chromosomes (the initial population).
3. We calculate the fitness of each chromosome using a fitness function. The higher the value of the fitness function for a certain chromosome, the better the solution represented by that chromosome.
4. We make a random choice of pairs of chromosomes, such that the probability of each chromosome to be chosen is proportional to its fitness.
5. For every chosen pair of chromosomes we randomly choose a location in the sequence ("crossover point"), such that from that point on the chromosomes exchange their genes. For example, given the two chromosomes `x1, x2, x3, x4, x5` and `y1, y2, y3, y4, y5` and assuming the crossover point is `3`, we get the two new chromosomes: `x1, x2, y3, y4, y5` and `y1, y2, x3, x4, x5`. Finally, we replace the original chromosomes by the new chromosomes (a new population).
6. With a small probability we randomly choose which chromosomes (if any) will undergo a mutation. In each of the chosen chromosomes a randomly chosen gene will be replaced with a random value.
7. We repeat steps 3-6 for a certain number of iterations.
8. Finally, we choose the chromosome with the highest fitness as the best solution for the problem.

Let's implement the above process for a toy problem. For our toy problem we will take a function `f`, which depends on 10 parameters. The function gets an input `x`, and it returns `True` if the number of parameters smaller than `x` is even. The fitness of a chromosome is just the number of inputs out of some training set for which the target function returns a correct answer when using the chromosome as a parameter set.

Here is a simple implementation:

```
import numpy as np
import random

def func(x, params):
    return ((params < x).sum() % 2 == 0)

def create_initial_population(size):
    return np.round(np.random.random(size * 10) * 30).reshape(size, 10)

def calculate_fitness(population, training_set, true_params):
    fitness = np.zeros(len(population))
    true_result = np.apply_along_axis(func, 1, training_set.reshape(-1, 1), params=true_params)
    for i, chromosome in enumerate(population):
        result = np.apply_along_axis(func, 1, training_set.reshape(-1, 1), params=chromosome)
        fitness[i] = (result == true_result).sum()
    return fitness.astype(int)

def select_chromosomes(population, fitness):
    half_population_size = int(len(population) / 2)
    chromosome_indices = []
    selected_pairs = np.zeros((half_population_size, 2))
    for i, value in enumerate(fitness):
        chromosome_indices.extend([i] * value)
    for j in range(half_population_size):
        selected_pairs[j, 0] = chromosome_indices[random.randint(0, len(chromosome_indices) - 1)]
        selected_pairs[j, 1] = chromosome_indices[random.randint(0, len(chromosome_indices) - 1)]
        return selected_pairs.astype(int)

def perform_crossover(population, selected_pairs):
    new_population = np.zeros((len(population), 10))
    for i in range(len(selected_pairs)):
        chromosome1 = population[selected_pairs[i, 0]]
        chromosome2 = population[selected_pairs[i, 1]]
        crossover_point = random.randint(0, 11)
        new_chromosome1 = np.zeros(10)
        new_chromosome2 = np.zeros(10)
        for j in range(10):
            if j < crossover_point:
                new_chromosome1[j] = chromosome1[j]
                new_chromosome2[j] = chromosome2[j]
            else:
                new_chromosome1[j] = chromosome2[j]
                new_chromosome2[j] = chromosome1[j]
        new_population[i * 2] = new_chromosome1
        new_population[i * 2 + 1] = new_chromosome2
    return new_population

def perform_mutation(population, probability):
    for i, chromosome in enumerate(population):
        rnd = random.random()
        if rnd < probability:
            location = random.randint(0, 9)
            population[1, location] = random.randint(0, 30)
    return population

def run():
    true_params = np.array([1, 2, 4, 7, 11, 16, 22, 29, 7, 16])
    training_set = np.array([1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19])
    population = create_initial_population(10)
    for i in range(20):
        fitness = calculate_fitness(population, training_set, true_params)
        selected_pairs = select_chromosomes(population, fitness)
        new_population = perform_crossover(population, selected_pairs)
        population = perform_mutation(new_population, 0.001)
    fitness = calculate_fitness(population, training_set, true_params)
    j = np.argmax(fitness)
    best = population[j]
    return best
```

Of course, we are not guaranteed to get a perfect parameter set, but with the right hyper-parameters (population size, mutation probability, number of iterations, etc.) we should get a descent approximation.